# Defining the coordinates for a Raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, coordinates, basemap

To clarify, I'm not trying to define the coordinate system for a raster; I know how to do that already.  However, what I'm having trouble with is actually getting the raster image to be the right scale.  For example, I know the coordinates of the corners of the image in decimal degrees, I know the width and height of the image in degrees, but when I define the coordinate system, it's blown way out of proportion and is much larger than it's supposed to be.  Is there a way to define the the scale and individual coordinates of a raster?  Or is Georeferencing my best bet?

I've got a google map static map API image download that I'm trying to overlay on a basemap.  What's the best strategy for that?  ArcPy or ArcGis desktop is helpful.

Comment: Manually create world file by projecting corner point first and simple math to compute cell size in metres.

Comment: You have it--you need to georeference the raster first. Right now the cell coordinate 1 to, let's say 1000. Georeferencing will tell the software that the 1 is actually 34.4839 (as an example).

Comment: Is there a way to georeference a batch?  As in, say I have several hundred of these static images that should, ideally, form a tileset or lay next to each other over a map.  Is there a way to reference all of them from one?  Or stitch them together in some way?